# Как считать только txt файлы с правами только на чтение для всех пользователей?

Tags: bash

Данный файл должен считать файлы с правами только на чтение для всех пользователей.

Что и куда необходимо дописать, чтобы он считал только *txt* файлы?

```
if ! [ -d $1 ]; then
    echo "Folder not found" & exit
fi
ls -alR $1 | grep r--r--r--|wc -l
```

Comment: А что значит "считать файлы"? Пока вы выводите их колличество?

Comment: @0xdb На данный момент мне выводится количество файлов с данными правами из папки всех ее подпапок , а мне надо чтоб этими файлами были только txt файлы

Comment: Я уже привёл пример в комментарии к предыдущему вопросу, а вы его зачемто удалили.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте с `find` (`man find`):

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
[ -d $1 ] || { echo "Folder not found"; exit 1; }
find $1 -type f -name "*.txt" -perm a+r | wc -l
```

Входные данные:

```
$ echo "\
./file1 444
./file2 666
./file3.txt 644
./file4.txt 444"| while read file perm; do touch $file; chmod $perm $file; done
```

Выведет с закомментированным `wc -l`, как и ожидалось, один файл:

```
./file4.txt
```

Comment: Мне надо чтобы были права только на чтение и чтоб выводилось число таких файлов .

Comment: Так? А что у вас выводится?

Comment: У меня выводятся все файлы с такими правами доступа не только txt , а с тем что вы предложили выводятся те у которых есть права не только на чтение

Comment: Проверте ошибки при копи+пасте. Привидите воиспроизводимый пример. У меня  всё работает.

Comment: спасибо, не знал, что у `find` есть параметр `-perm`...

Comment: @JeniaSapeginskiy Дополнил данными. Покажите, что у вас не так выводится.